# NameError: name 'QColor' is not defined

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-2.18

I try to set style settings in QGIS 2.18. However I get `QColor` error. Here is my code:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()

layer.setDrawingStyle('SingleBandPseudoColor')
stats = layer.dataProvider().bandStatistics(1, QgsRasterBandStats.Min | QgsRasterBandStats.Max)
minVal = int(stats.minimumValue + 0.5)
maxVal = int(stats.maximumValue + 0.5)
mean = (minVal + maxVal) / 2
s1 = str((minVal * 2 + maxVal) / 3)
s2 = str((minVal + maxVal * 2) / 3)
item0 = QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(minVal, QColor(10, 100, 10), str(minVal) + ' - ' + s1)
item1 = QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(mean, QColor( 153, 125, 25), s1 + ' - ' + s2)
item2 = QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(maxVal, QColor(255, 255, 255), s2 + ' - ' + str(maxVal))
fcn = QgsColorRampShader(minVal, maxVal)
fcn.setColorRampType(QgsColorRampShader.INTERPOLATED)
fcn.setColorRampItemList([item0, item1, item2])
layer.renderer().shader().setRasterShaderFunction(fcn)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:/users/mustaf~1/appdata/local/temp/tmpippgsf.py", line 10, in <module>
    item0 = QgsColorRampShader.ColorRampItem(minVal, QColor(10, 100, 10), str(minVal) + ' - ' + s1)
NameError: name 'QColor' is not defined
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to import classes before you can use them. At the top of your script put

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import QColor
```

or

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
```

if you want to import all the classes at once

Comment: yes yes I have already seen the problem, it is really foolish mistake. Thanks anyway!